# routes issue in CodeIgniter Project

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have been working on a code Igniter project and I am almost done. I finally added Pagination but have one issue. When I scroll through my pagination links on my page and then click to go to my home page, I get an error message. Trying to break this down so that others can better understand it, my blog page, which has pagination has this URL:

proj1/index.php/blog

my URL for the home page is:

proj1/index.php/home

when I click on my pagination link for "2" which shows the next set of blogs, I got to this URL:

proj1/index.php/blog/2

Now if I am on blog/2 and then click "home" it takes me here:

proj1/index.php/blog/home

if I go to my resume page I see this:

proj1/index.php/blog/work

Basically, I am not going back to my home page nor my resume page. Is anyone able to help fix this problem? Thank you for your help!!

Here is what my blog controller looks like:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    //This function begins to construct the controller. 
    public function __construct()

      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Blog_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        //pagination being loaded from the library 
        $this->load->library('pagination');
      }

    public function index()

    {
      //This line sets the page for the base URL
      $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog');
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->Blog_model->count_items();
      $config['per_page'] = 2;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

      $data['title'] = 'Blog archive';


      $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
      $start = '';

      $slug = '';

      $data['blog'] = $this->Blog_model->get_items($config['per_page'],                           jjjj      $this->uri->segment(2));

      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('blog/index', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug = NULL)

    {

      $data['blog_item'] = $this->Blog_model->get_blog($slug);

      if (empty($data['blog_item']))
        {
          show_404();
        }

      $data['title'] = $data['blog_item']['title'];

      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('blog/view', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    public function create()

    {
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $data['title'] = 'Create a Blog Entry';

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)

        {
          $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('blog/create');
          $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else

        {
          $this->Blog_model->set_blog();
          redirect('blog');
        }
    }
     }
```

Here is my blog model:

```
    <?php
    class Blog_model extends CI_Model {

    //This function connects to the database and loads it. 
    public function __construct()

    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    }

     //This function counts all of the items in the blog table. 
    public function count_items() 

     { 
     return $this->db->count_all('blog');
     }

       //function pulls items out of the array specifically by newest date                      first. 
    function get_items($limit, $offset) 

    {
    $data = array();
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('entry_date', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('blog');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
     }
    }
   $query->free_result();
   return $data;
   }

   public function set_blog()

    {
  $this->load->helper('url');

  $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

  $data = array(
  'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
  'slug' => $slug,
  'body' => $this->input->post('body')
  );

    return $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
    }
    }
```

Finally, my routes look like this:

```
$route['message'] = 'contact/create';
$route['contact'] = 'contact';
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
$route['create'] = 'blog/create';
$route['blog'] = 'blog';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Thank you for any help and please let me know if you need me to post more information. I do not think that this is a hard issue to fix. However, it has stumped me! Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: you have define $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog'); which set base_url

Comment: May I know what code snippet you are using for link to home page

Comment: I do believe that the problem may be in the $config variable but how do I fix it? What do you mean by "code snippet to link to home page"? I do use this: index.php/home is that what you mean?

Comment: yes I mean this ==> index.php/home

Comment: When I change $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog'); to $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/home'); Everything does work except the pagination-when I click on 2 or 3 to show me other blog entrees I get a 404 error message. Thank you for your help if you have other solutions I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should change the

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog');
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/home');
```

I would change the index method in the controller to page and than change the config base_url to:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog/page/');
```

You can than change the route:

```
$route['blog'] = 'blog/page/1';
```

Than you can remove the following route since it is no longer necessary:

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
```

Than it should all work.

Edit:
I believe the 404 is because the pagination class checked the wrong url segment. Mayby the following could also help (try different values).

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
```

Comment: Good day, thank you for the information. I have made the following changes: $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/blog/page/'); and the routes I now have: $route['blog'] = 'blog/page/1'; However, it is still not working, I am getting a 404 error message whenever I try heading to my blog page. It appears that the route: $route['blog'] = 'blog'; is needed! Thank you for any more help!